# How to merge records together

Tags: sql, jsf, jpa, weld

i am able to update the database so for each section a user saves it saves there work fine, in the correct column of the database, but what i am now trying to achieve is instead of saving into a new row, check there `studentNumber` and if it already has a record in the table (which it will have to to get this far ) update the columns to that record rather than starting a new one

how can i do that ?

currently this is my code :

this is the u.i. where they select the value and press submit

```
                            <p:spinner id="ajaxspinner80-100" value="#{editMarkingBean.markSectionTwo.markSectionTwo}"
                                       stepFactor="1"  min="80" max="100" disabled="#{formBean.number != 8}">
                                <p:ajax update="ajaxspinnervalue" process="@this" />
                            </p:spinner>
```

the save button

```
                    <p:commandButton action="#{editMarkingBean.markSectionTwo}" value="#{bundle.buttonSave}" update=":growl" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
```

the backing bean is :

```
@Named(value = "editMarkingBean")
@ViewScoped
public class EditMarkingController {

    private String searchString;
    private String ordering;
    private String criteria;
    private String match;
    private Date today;
    private String caseMatch;
    private int spinnerField;
    private Marking markSectionOne;
    private Marking studentNumber;
    private Marking markSectionTwo;

    private MarkingService markingService;

    private Marking markToEdit;

    @Inject
    private MarkingFacade markingFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //this.markToEdit = this.markingFacade.find(studentNumber);
        this.markSectionTwo = new Marking();
    }

    public String markSectionTwo() {
        this.markingFacade.edit(markSectionTwo);
        this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
        markSectionTwo = new Marking();
        this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
        // now navigating to the next page
        return "/lecturer/marking/marking-section-three";
    }

    private void setMessage(String message) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        fc.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message, ""));
    }

    public Marking getMarkSectionTwo() {
        return markSectionTwo;
    }

    public void setMarkSectionTwo(Marking markSectionTwo) {
        this.markSectionTwo = markSectionTwo;
    }

    public String getSearchString() {
        return searchString;
    }

    public void setSearchString(String searchString) {
        this.searchString = searchString;
    }

    public String getOrdering() {
        return ordering;
    }

    public void setOrdering(String ordering) {
        this.ordering = ordering;
    }

    public String getCriteria() {
        return criteria;
    }

    public void setCriteria(String criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }

    public String getMatch() {
        return match;
    }

    public void setMatch(String match) {
        this.match = match;
    }

    public Date getToday() {
        return today;
    }

    public void setToday(Date today) {
        this.today = today;
    }

    public String getCaseMatch() {
        return caseMatch;
    }

    public void setCaseMatch(String caseMatch) {
        this.caseMatch = caseMatch;
    }

    public int getSpinnerField() {
        return spinnerField;
    }

    public void setSpinnerField(int spinnerField) {
        this.spinnerField = spinnerField;
    }

    public Marking getMarkSectionOne() {
        return markSectionOne;
    }

    public void setMarkSectionOne(Marking markSectionOne) {
        this.markSectionOne = markSectionOne;
    }

    public Marking getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(Marking studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public MarkingService getMarkingService() {
        return markingService;
    }

    public void setMarkingService(MarkingService markingService) {
        this.markingService = markingService;
    }

    public MarkingFacade getMarkingFacade() {
        return markingFacade;
    }

    public void setMarkingFacade(MarkingFacade markingFacade) {
        this.markingFacade = markingFacade;
    }

}
```

but currently only adds a new row with the data to the database rather than trying to merge it with the data already contained in the database for a student with a certain student number

how can i achieve this ? thanks guys for your help :)

EDIT :

I have tried :

```
 private Marking markToEdit;

    @Inject
    private MarkingFacade markingFacade;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.markToEdit = this.markingFacade.find(studentNumber);
        //this.markSectionTwo = new Marking();
    }

    public String markSectionTwo() {
        this.markingFacade.edit(markSectionTwo);
        this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
       // markSectionTwo = new Marking();
        //this.setMessage("Mark Saved");
        // now navigating to the next page
        return "/lecturer/marking/marking-section-three";
    }
```

but get the error :

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke public void sws.control.EditMarkingController.init() on sws.control.EditMarkingController@4109691f
root cause

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke public void sws.control.EditMarkingController.init() on sws.control.EditMarkingController@4109691f
root cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
root cause

javax.ejb.EJBException
root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a quite similar approach as yours, but with different names. I'll post it here, so I think you can have some idea.

My way is to check the entity explicitly before merging it.

My JSF CRUD looks like this

xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>DataSource Manager</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="ds">

        <p:spacer height="10" />
        <p:fieldset legend="Insert/Edit Data Source">
        <p:panel id="insertUpdateForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

            <p:outputLabel for="name" value="Data Source Name:" style="width:100px;"/>  
            <p:inputText id="name" value="#{dataSourceMB.dataSource.name}"/>


            <p:outputLabel for="user" value="User:" style="width:100px;"/>  
            <p:inputText id="user" value="#{dataSourceMB.dataSource.user}"/>


            <p:outputLabel for="driver" value="Driver:" style="width:100px;"/>  
            <p:inputText id="driver" value="#{dataSourceMB.dataSource.driver}" />

        </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel>
            <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{dataSourceMB.saveDataSource}" update="dsList,insertUpdateForm" />
            <p:commandButton value="Clear" action="#{dataSourceMB.clearDataSource}" update="insertUpdateForm" />
            <p:commandButton value="Test Connection" action="#{dataSourceMB.testConnection}"/>
        </p:panel>

        </p:fieldset>


        <p:spacer height="10" />
        <p:fieldset legend="Data Sources">    
        <p:panel>
            <p:dataTable 
                var="ds" 
                value="#{dataSourceMB.listDataSources}" 
                paginator="true" rows="10"  
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100"
                id="dsList">  

            <p:column headerText="ID">                
                <h:outputText value="#{ds.id}" />  
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">                  
                <h:outputText value="#{ds.name}" />  
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="JDBC">                  
                <h:outputText value="#{ds.jdbc} " />  
            </p:column>

            <!-- check http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ for icons -->             

            <p:column headerText="" style="width:2%">  
                <p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="#{dataSourceMB.editDataSource}" title="Edit" update=":ds:insertUpdateForm">   
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{ds}" target="#{dataSourceMB.selectedDataSource}" />  
                </p:commandButton>  
            </p:column>                           
            <p:column headerText="" style="width:2%">  
                <p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-trash" action="#{dataSourceMB.removeDataSource}" title="Remove" update=":ds:insertUpdateForm,dsList">  
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{ds}" target="#{dataSourceMB.selectedDataSource}" />  
                </p:commandButton>              
            </p:column>  
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

my managed bean

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import DataSourceEJB;
import JSFUtilEJB;
import DataSource;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DataSourceMB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 871363306742707990L;
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataSourceMB.class);

    @EJB
    private JSFUtilEJB jsfUtilEJB;

    @EJB
    private DataSourceEJB dataSourceEJB;

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private DataSource selectedDataSource;
    private List<DataSource> listDataSources;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            this.dataSource = new DataSource();
            this.listDataSources = this.dataSourceEJB.listDataSources();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            jsfUtilEJB.addErrorMessage(e,"Could not list");
        }
    }

    public void removeDataSource(){
        try {
            this.dataSourceEJB.removeDataSource(this.selectedDataSource);
            jsfUtilEJB.addInfoMessage("Removed "+this.selectedDataSource.getName());

            if (this.dataSource != null && this.dataSource.getId() != null && this.dataSource.getId().equals(this.selectedDataSource.getId())){
                this.dataSource = null;
            }
            this.listDataSources = this.dataSourceEJB.listDataSources();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            jsfUtilEJB.addErrorMessage(e,"Could not remove");
        }
    }

    public void saveDataSource(){
        try {
            this.dataSourceEJB.saveDataSource(this.dataSource);
            jsfUtilEJB.addInfoMessage("Saved "+this.dataSource.getName());

            this.dataSource = new DataSource();
            this.listDataSources = this.dataSourceEJB.listDataSources();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            jsfUtilEJB.addErrorMessage(e,"Could not save");
        }
    }

    public void editDataSource(){
        this.dataSource = this.selectedDataSource;

    }

    public void clearDataSource(){
        this.dataSource = new DataSource();
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public DataSource getSelectedDataSource() {
        return selectedDataSource;
    }

    public void setSelectedDataSource(DataSource selectedDataSource) {
        this.selectedDataSource = selectedDataSource;
    }

    public List<DataSource> getListDataSources() {
        return listDataSources;
    }

    public void setListDataSources(List<DataSource> listDataSources) {
        this.listDataSources = listDataSources;
    }

}
```

my EJB

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import DataSource;

@Stateless
public class DataSourceEJB {

    @Inject
    private BaseService baseService;

    public List<DataSource> listDataSources() {
        return this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().getAll();
    }


    public void removeDataSource(DataSource ds) throws Exception {
        DataSource a = this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().find(ds.getId()); 
        this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().delete(a);      
    }

    public void saveDataSource(DataSource ds) throws Exception {
        DataSource a = this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().find(ds.getId());
        if (a == null){
            this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().add(ds);
        }else{
            this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().edit(ds);
        }       
    }

    public DataSource getById(long id) {
        return this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().find(id);
    }

    public DataSource getByName(String name) {
        return this.baseService.getDataSourceDAO().findByName(name);
    }

}
```

DAO

```
public E find(Long id) {
    return (E)entityManager.find(clazz, id);
}

public void add(E entity) throws Exception {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
}


public E edit(E entity) throws Exception {
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}


public void delete(E entity) throws Exception {
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, is it in the EJB where you check before merging ?, as i am unsure of how yours is actually working

Comment: in the saveDataSource() method

Comment: Thanks, i have been trying to get it working on my code but so far am having no luck, do you think you could show me how to start it on my example by any chance